# How to call controller method from another controller?

Tags: magento-1.9

Created a model in which the form validation on the beck

```
  public function validation_form()
{
    $error = false;
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($name, 'NotEmpty')) {
        $error = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Name is required');
    }
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($message, 'NotEmpty')) {
        $error = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Message is required');
    }
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($subject, 'NotEmpty')) {
        $error = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Subject is required');
    }
    if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
        $error = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Email is required');
    }
    if ($error) {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And there is a method in the controller that adds data to the database.

```
 public function postAction()
        {
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($post) {

                $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name');
                $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
                $phone = $this->getRequest()->getPost('phone');
                $user_agent = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent();
                $remote_ip = Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
                $subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('subject');
                $other_subject = $this->getRequest()->getPost('other');
                $message = $this->getRequest()->getPost('message');
                $created_at = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
etc...
```

How to connect function postAction() to validation so that the variables "$name, $email, etc..." are available in the validation model.

Path to the controller mymodul/feedback/controllers/IndexController.php

Path to the validation mymodul/feedback/model/Validation.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues here:

1. your method `validation_form()` does not take any parameters. It should be something like `public function validation_form($name, $message, $subject, $email)`. Else, the method does not have access to any of the values from `postAction()`.
2. I don't knot if you can throw an `Exception()` with an empty message, and I'm not sure if the `validate_form()` method will work as expected, but you can try and open another question if new errors occur :)
3. From your `postAction()`, call the method like this:

`Mage::getModel('mymodule/validation')->validate_form($name, $message, $subject, $email);`

...assuming you defined your model namespace in your `config.xml` file. If you didn't, search for a tutorial how to define a basic Magento 1 module - it's easy ;)

Comment: Thanks, passed the values to the function and it all worked, thanks again)